# Web Audio API: outputChannelCount not working when I inherit from AudioWorkletProcessor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, web-audio-api, super, audio-worklet

I have the following example. I try to pass the `options` parameter via calling `super(...)`. When I do this, I don't get 2 output channels as I specified, instead I only get 1 output channel.

```
class Processor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    constructor() {
        super({outputChannelCount: [2]});
    }

    process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
        console.log("output channels: ", outputs[0].length);
        return true;
    }
}

registerProcessor('processor', Processor);
```

When I try the same passing the `options` to the `AudioWorkletNode` instead, like in the following example, it works as expected.

```
    let audioContext = new AudioContext();
    (async () => {
        await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('processor.js');
        audioWorkletNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'processor', {outputChannelCount: [2]});
        audioWorkletNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
    })();
```

This is not working in any browser I tried.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Is there something in the Web Audio API specification that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you describe is expected. The constructor of an `AudioWorkletProcessor` doesn't take any arguments as defined by the IDL definition here:

https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioWorkletProcessor

The options that you pass to the `AudioWorkletNode` constructor on the main thread get stored as something called the [`pending processor construction data`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#pending-processor-construction-data). They get applied automatically and there is no way to change them from within the processor.

I guess this is to make sure the `AudioWorkletNode` and its corresponding `AudioWorkletProcessor` always have the same configuration. If you could change the configuration within the processor the `AudioWorkletNode` would be out of sync until the information travelled back again.

Comment: Interesting, I am referring to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor/AudioWorkletProcessor
where the constructor seems to have the options as parameter..
Looking at the specification I cannot see this possibility
https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioWorketProcessor-constructors

Comment: I think it's confusing since all the options mentioned on MDN are passed to the custom processor which inherits from `AudioWorkletProcessor` but the `AudioWorkletProcessor` itself doesn't accept those options. However I noticed a little inconsistency in the examples in the spec and opened an issue to discuss this further: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/2491.